# How to invoke non-static method from Java class using JSTL?

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

I think this isn't new issue but I haven't found solution yet so i hope the answers to this post may clarify my problem.

Suppose that i have a class which contains a method getPersonnels(String name) that return List. Of course this class isn't a JavaBean, just trivial class without property called List personnels. How can i invoke this method using JSTL and store it to local variable in jsp page?

Answer (score 0):

Use a servlet as controller.

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    String name = request.getParameter("name");
    List<Personnel> personnels = personnelDAO.find(name);
    request.setAttribute("personnels", personnels);
    request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/personnels.jsp").forward(request, response); 
}
```

Map it on a certain `url-pattern` and then invoke *that* URL instead of the JSP one.

In `personnels.jsp` just access it the usual way.

```
<table>
    <c:forEach items="${personnels}" var="personnel">
        <tr>
            <td>${personnel.id}</td>
            <td>${personnel.name}</td>
            <td>${personnel.jobdescription}</td>
        </tr>
    </c:forEach>
</table>
```

Comment: Dont we have something equivalent to that we do as `<%= objName.methodName() %>` in scriptlets . should it be done in the way as you explained above ?